MesloLGS NF Italic font does not get installed
It does not installs for me also after clicking on install :  MesloLGS NF Italic.ttf
Shows installing but then stops

Provide more details. Screenshot or any error. And the way you are installing it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
